# Can anyone tell me how to validate a date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript

Below is my code...

```
/**
* Check whether the values entered in the date fields are in dd/mm/yyyy format 
* and whether the dd, mm and yyyy values are valid
**/
function validateDateFormat(obj)
{
 var dtStr=obj.value;
 var year;
 var day;
 var month;
 var leap=0;
 var valid=true;
 var oth_valid=true;
 var feb=false;
 var validDate=true;
 var Ret=true;

  if(obj.readOnly==false)
  {
    if(dtStr!="" && dtStr!=null)
    {
        year=dtStr.substr(6,4);
        month=dtStr.substr(3,2);
        day=dtStr.substr(0,2);

        if(year=="0000" || year<1900 || month=="00" || day=="00" || dtStr.length<10)
        {
            validDate=false;
        }

        if(validDate==true)
        {
            leap=year%4;

         if(month=="02")
         {
                feb=true;
         }


        if(leap==0 && month=="02")
            {
                if(day>29)
                {
                    valid=false;
                    feb=true;
                }
            }

            else if(month=="02" && day>28)
            {    
                valid=false;
                feb=true;
            }

            if(feb==false)
            {       
                if(month=="03" || month=="01" || month=="05" || month=="07" || month=="08" || month=="10" || month=="12")
                {
                    if(day>31)
                    {                       
                        oth_valid=false;
                    }
                }

                else if(month=="04" || month==06 || month=="09" || month=="11") 
                {
                    if(day>30)
                    {                       
                        oth_valid=false;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    oth_valid=false;
                }

            }
        }
    }   

     if(valid==false || oth_valid==false || validDate==false)
    {
        alert("Please enter the valid date in the dd/mm/yyyy Format only");
        obj.value="";
        obj.focus();
        Ret=false;
    }
    return Ret;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to validate a date input string:

```
String input = "12/05/2011";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(input);
    // it's good
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // it's bad
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... can u please tell me how the validation is done in javascript

Comment: @Susmitha: oh sorry, I didn't realize you wanted JavaScript. Your question was tagged with 'java' and your code was originally formatted such that the block didn't contain the parts with 'function' and 'var'. Unfortunately it's not as simple in JavaScript as far as I know. You should tag your question with 'javascript' so it attracts the right people to answer.

Comment: Thank you WhiteFang for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try to create a temporary date with the string, 
and check that the date and month match the input.
If you know that every user uses dd-mm-yyyy format a date can be made with
Date.parse(string)- but if you have any US users, better make the Date
with the constructor.

function isvalid_dmy(s){
    // ddmmyyyy date string
    var day, A= s.split(/\D+/);
    for(var i= 0; i<3; i++){
        A[i]= parseInt(A[i], 10)
    }
    A[1]-= 1;
    try{
        day= new Date(A[2], A[1], A[0]);
        if(day.getMonth()== A[1] && day.getDate()== A[0]){
            return day.toLocaleDateString();
            // or return true
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch(er){
        return false;// or handle bad date here 
    }
}


//test
var day1= '13-05-2011', day2= '31-04-2011';

day1+'= '+isvalid_dmy(day1)+'\n'+
day2+'= '+isvalid_dmy(day2);
/*  returned value: (String)
13-05-2011= Friday, May 13, 2011
31-04-2011= false
*/
```